# Assigning a shortcut to a service

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, osx-yosemite

I am running 10.10 Yosemite. I recently created a service which looks like this. The service is simply suppose to launch a calculator. I tested it out by pressing play and it launches the calculator.
This is what it looks like
[image]

I then attempted to add a shortcut to the service from the keyboard shortcut and this is what it looks like
[image]

However now when the menu bar is on finder and I press Shift option p nothing happens I only hear a beep. Any suggestions on why the shortcut is not launching ?

Comment: Do you see `PathFinder` when you click Finder > Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing as a Workflow in the picture - though it does appear to be correctly showing as a service in the Keyboard prefs.
Are you sure they're one & the same Automator file?

You could maybe quickly re-save that one as a Service, see if it makes any difference...

File menu > Convert to…
Select Service.
Save.
Check it appears in the Finder Service menu

Tried to squeeze it all into one picture…

[image]

You could also check by opening the service in Automator, directly from `~/Library/Services` just to test it's correct.

Comment: So I realized that the shortcut I was using playing around with doesnt work. Infact i had to launch the service first manually for it to work.I wish there was a way to find out if a certain shortcut is being used somewhere else

Comment: It worked fine here - I built exactly what your question appears to say, just to test it & the key combo correctly launched Calculator. If a shortcut is already in use it will flag both the dupe & the original.

Comment: Yeah. I was testing it with a simpler shortcut. Command + p

Comment: hmm… that'll be 'Print' then ;-) Not sure it'll flag a dupe if the dupe is not in that list, but in a menu somewhere unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

I have come up with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74152132/17517452) workaround: Use

`System Preferences` -> `Keyboard` -> `Shortcuts` -> **`App Shortcuts`**

screenshot [image]

There you have to spell out the name of your service. In contrast to *Shortcuts -> Services* this actually works for me.